# Converting to chomsky normal form

Tags: context-free-grammar, chomsky-normal-form

I'm currently learning about CNF and I'm a bit confused.

Given this grammar:

`S -> ab | aSb`

will result to CNF:

`S -> AB | XB`

`X -> AY`

`Y -> AB | XB`

`A -> a`

`B -> b`

How about this:

`S -> c | aSa | bSb`

Can someone boost me up a little on this one. thanks.

Comment: In what way(s) does the technique you used for your 1st example fail you on the second?  In particular, the second rule of your first example looks a lot like what you have in the second example, so a similar technique should work.

Comment: I'm having doubts. Getting `Y` seems unnecessary because you can do `X->aS` instead of having `Y->S` and `X->AY`. Why did the 1st example created the variable `Y` to replace `S`? I dont understand.

Comment: `Y` isn't necessary, but it isn't wrong either.  There are separate techniques for minimizing grammars.  And `X->aS` isn't legal in CNF.

Comment: thank you very much. what would you prefer, replacing the `S`(getting the`Y`) or getting the shorter(getting `X->aS`)?

Comment: `X->aS` isn't legal in CNF.

Comment: sorry. `X->aS` isn't legal. I meant `X->AS` because `A->a`. So is `X->AS` legal?